# Storing data into custom taxonomies VS post custom fields (post meta)

Tags: custom-taxonomy, custom-field

I'm wondering what's more efficient when it comes to performing search for data. I am building a job board where I have an option to store information like:

- Company Name (Searchable)
- City (Searchable)
- Skill (Searchable)
- Location (Searchable

While fields like 'City', 'Skill' and even 'Location' can be stored as custom taxonomies; I'm not sure if storing 'Company Name' as taxonomy is a good option.

Why am I concerned?

Well, with custom taxonomies my life becomes simpler. I can fetch data simply by using ?city=ABC&skill=XYZ (and so on). This doesn't seem to work for custom post fields (or does it?)

If I've to fetch data from custom post fields; I'll have to write complex queries with WP_Query and fetch / display results. But I wonder if the effort is really worth it.

Would really make a difference if I choose to store Company Name and other searchable information as taxonomy? My opinion so far is that anything searchable should go into taxonomy and other data can go into custom post fields.

What do you think?